# Accidently moved root partition by error

Tags: linux, root-filesystem

cb@coreboot-bm-4:~$ pwd
/home/cb
cb@coreboot-bm-4:~$ sudo mv /* ADL-P/

and now I can't do anything

when I try something like:

cb@coreboot-bm-4:~$ ls
-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not only the the binaries in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are moved. But even if you run them directly, they won't be able to find their libraries. In other words,you won't be able to move back `/` from that shell.

Many VM providers offer you the option to mount a rescue system, or other ISO. If you can upload your own ISO, I recommend: https://www.system-rescue.org/. Or use an installer ISO and try to access the shell.

For example, the standard Debian installer offers "rescue mode" by selecting `Advanced options` -> `Rescue mode`. Click through the dialogs and when it asks which filesystem root to use select `Do not use a root filesystem` and `Execute a shell in the installer environment`.

Regardless if you used debian, systemrescuecd or any other method. Once you have a shell:

1. Identify the root device with `fdisk -l`
2. Mount the root device: `mkdir -p /mnt/root && mount /dev/vda1 /mnt/root`. (replace `/dev/vda1` with the actual device!)
3. Move everything back: `mv /mnt/root/ADL-P/* /mnt/root`

In some rescue shells, like the debian one, you can get an error: `Can't rename ... : Directory not empty`. **Only** in that case you need to use the `-n` option: `mv -n /mnt/root/ADL-P/* /mnt/root`

4. Reboot the system: `reboot` (perhaps you need to manually remove the ISO from your provider's dashboard)

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Try /ADL-P/usr/bin/sudo /ADL-P/usr/bin/mv /ADL-P /

Edit:
Just found this one
https://askubuntu.com/questions/951134/accidentally-moved-usr-bin

Comment: cb@coreboot-bm-4:~$ FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/sudo FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/mv /ADL-P /
bash: FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory

Comment: Humm lets go step by step lets try to Locate /usr/bin in the new path so
FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/ls FSP_Integration/ADL-P/

Comment: Right, but how to locate /usr/bin to new path?

Comment: Does FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/ls FSP_Integration/ADL-P/ return error? if not you have located new "root" path, now invoking FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/cd .. located u un the new use bin

Comment: FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/<command> executes every command as it would be un the past now the last step is mover the files to /

Comment: cb@coreboot-bm-4:~$ FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/ls FSP_Integration/ADL-P/
bash: FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
cb@coreboot-bm-4:~$

Comment: Root files are moved to -> FSP_Integration/ADL-P/

Comment: When I checked, there is no ls, cp or mv bins inside /usr/bin/

Comment: But even the existing binaries in /usr/bin/ gives error -> cb@coreboot-bm-4:~$ FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/lsb_release
bash: FSP_Integration/ADL-P/usr/bin/lsb_release: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: And are you able to reboot your system?

Comment: No, my VM is a remote VM, i can only SSH, since i have an existing SSH alive, so i am able to access it via SSH only and trying to recover, but rest i am not able to create any new SSH connection to VM.

Comment: If i will reboot, i will loose the existing SSH connection and will totally black out from VM. Is there any other way to copy those root files back to their directory?

Comment: does /bin/systemctl status ssh or /usr/Bin/systemctl status ssh give you any info